# ADT Plugin can't install: Missing requirement: Android Development Tools

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried to install ADT plugin on eclipse helios windows 64 bits classic. I got this error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you MUST run eclipse as administrator to install plugins under vista or 7!!!  right click on the eclipse.exe file (not the shortcut).  if you still have problems, try the step below.

one reason this can happen is that you first need to include the release compatible with your version of eclipse:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno (or helios, ganimede, indigo, etc)

in case you are missing the android sdk, download from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

after installing it, you must go inside the folder c:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/platforms/  and create a new (empty) folder 'android-7'.  then create a folder named temp in c:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk/ and you will be prompted to download SDK when you start eclipse again (always as administrator)

finally, restart and you should be ok

PS: you must update your eclipse (under HELP) and then exit it.  restart in admin mode and open your Android SDK packages (not HELP, the tab on its left [not at my workstation right now, will reedit later]).

without installing basically everything there (some 3 to 12 hours, depending on your connection speed), you will not have a complete environment and some compilation simply will not work.

Comment: Your tip applies to Linux as well; I'm on Linux Mint 12 and Eclipse Indigo and this ridiculously confusing and unnecessary error message turns up there as well.  The solution is to gksudo eclipse.

Comment: this problem does NOT occur in ubuntu 12.10 with eclipse juno

Answer (score 3):

The eclipse version is old, you need to provide the `org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0` library to it.

See instructions here : http://code.google.com/intl/es/eclipse/docs/faq.html#wstinstallerror

or , i would recommed to upgrade to Eclipse Indigo, which won't have this problem..

Comment: I get the same error on the 64-Bit version of eclipse 3.7.2 when trying to install ADT 18.0.0 (which is the Indigo version btw), so chances are the ide being "outdated" is not necessarily the only reason for this error to pop up?

Comment: not "old", got the problem with eclipse Juno, launched 15 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse Juno (i.e. 4.x.x) on Win 7, and encountering problems installing Android ADT Plugin for eclipse, see the following to fix it:

1. go to where the eclipse.exe file located (default: C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse)
2. NOT left click (run it) but RIGHT click on eclipse.exe
3. pick run as administrator.

Then it runs. Next, just follow the relevant Android guide on the matter
(http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Comment: A more detailed answer was given by tony gil first.

Answer (score 0):

Right-clicking on the eclipse.exe file and selecting "Run as administrator" will give you file access privileges that will permit ADT updates via the Eclipse/Android SDK Manager in the Eclipse "Window" drop-down.

In my case, my Windows 7 system was lacking the required "Android SDK Platform-tools 16.0.1" plug-in. I suggest re-starting Windows after completing this plug-in installation. Once I re-started Eclipse (Juno), the error message "Could not find C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe!" was eliminated.