# I screwed up my eclipse setup, and need help fixing it

Tags: android

Ok I have eclipse Galileo Build id: 20100218-1602, I was having a problem with my Logcat, and seen a post that recommended updating the SDK, so I updated the SDK to the latest version. This made the eclipse program give me a message saying this SDK needs ADT 14 or higher. I have tried to update the ADT without success. At this point, I've tried to delete and uninstall everything, and that has been impossible. There is no uninstall program and the eclipse folder will not delete. Does anyone have a recommendation on how to delete eclipse from my Window 7 computer? Or a way to revert back to my old SDK? This is driving me nuts. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the Eclipse folder cannot delete? There must be a program that's still taking ownership of the folder. Simply restart your computer and then delete the folder, and whatever process owning that folder should be terminated.

Comment: I shut down all programs... But I did not restart the computer. I'll try that now. Be right back!

Comment: Just confirming that, yes you can delete the Eclipse folder to uninstall it: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/157291/#page_top

Comment: Try updating your Eclipse as well.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I don't know why I didn't restart to begin with. Whatever process was going on in the background stopped and now I was able to delete.

Comment: Hey Ghost, updating is what got me into this mess. Now I'm just trying to reinstall to get back to where I was. Thanks Guys!

Comment: Ok, I've reinstalled elipse, now I'm trying to add the Android Plug-in, but I get an error.  Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Missing requirement: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found

Comment: Any Ideas to why the ADT won't install?

Comment: i do NOT recommend radical updating of ADT, SDK or whatever (like when you have revision 15 and need to upgrade to rev 21 - because of ICS / JB devices).  even though it does work (sorta), if you have other plugins (like MOTODEV), you will run into a quagmire of problems.  i recommend a clean reinstall of ADT bundle.

Answer (score 1):

ADT 14 works only with Eclipse Indigo version.

Eclipse does not need any installation it contains a direct runnable exe. If you are unable to delete the folder then try restart your PC or try a software that will unlock the folder or atleast show you the processes that have a lock on that particular folder. You can close these processes on your own.

Once you install ADT 14 with eclipse indigo update the Android SDK. It should be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that it would not work with Galileo to late, but I could not get it to revert back to the old SDK, I'm finally getting it to reinstall. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend a new install.  while an update will easily take 2 to 4 hours (from rev 15 to rev21, with appropriate sdks, etc), you can download the complete ADT ECLIPSE bundle in much less time (410 MB) on regular 10Mb broadband.

i tried updating on Java EE Indigo from rev 15 to rev 21 (sdk tools) and ran into a big, big mess.  not worth it.  gave up and reinstalled eclipse.  faster process and much sturdier result.

[Download ADT bundle here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), then
[follow these instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html)

since ECLIPSE is an executable that uses java virtual machine to run, it does NOT need to be installed (especially handy on windows).  just unpack the bundle into your Program Files folder and execute the file eclipse.exe (if running under Vista / 7, you MAY need to run always as Administrator, i have a [published recipe for Admin installing here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143853/adt-plugin-cant-install-missing-requirement-android-development-tools/11371883#11371883)).

after installing and checking if everything is OK, rename or delete your OLD eclipse folder.

if you use the same workspace that you were using previously, you should not miss a beat: the same projects will be open as when you last left your workspace, and your run and debug configs should be there, too.

ECLIPSE ROCKS!