# ADT not installing on Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, eclipse-kepler

I have downloaded Eclipse Kepler and now trying to instal Android ADT. I am facing the below issue.

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206)
  Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.3.v201404151837-1123206) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

1. Initially I tried to install using https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ . I got the error.
2. Later I downloaded the package and installed from local but getting the above error. 
   Any suggestions ?

I tried running the eclipse in administrator mode but still getting the same error. 
[ADT Plugin can't install: Missing requirement: Android Development Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143853/adt-plugin-cant-install-missing-requirement-android-development-tools)

Any help is appreciated. Note: In my system, Android SDK is working fine in my Eclipse Indigo working perfectly in my system.

Answer (score 2):

ADT might depend on other plugins, such as Eclipse Web Tools. You need to make sure you checked `Contact all update sites during install to find required software`. Eclipse will then look up dependencies in other update sites, like the default Kepler one.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by unzipping the eclipse again from the original zipped file. Right now everything works fine.

But thanks lulian Dragos.